# Can't receive Location Updates with BroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android, location, google-play-services, google-api-client

I'm trying to make an app to get periodic location updates and send the location to a webservice using http post.

The problem im facing is that not able to use the Location service of GoogleApiServices on background.
I followed [this code](https://gist.github.com/blackcj/20efe2ac885c7297a676), but he used LocationClient that is deprecated now. I'm following the comments of the post but I'm still not able to make it run on background. I've been able to use GoogleApiServices with and activity and it worked fine but didn't worked on background and for this reason I tried to make a service and a BroadcastReceiver.

Here is my code:

*LocationReceiver.java*

```
public class LocationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("LocationReceiver", "Something Received");
    }
}
```

*BackgroundLocationService.java*

```
public class BackgroundLocationService extends Service implements
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

    private static final String TAG = "BGLocationSvc";

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    // Flag that indicates if a request is underway.
    private boolean mInProgress;

    private Boolean servicesAvailable = false;
    private PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock;

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public BackgroundLocationService getServerInstance() {
            return BackgroundLocationService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.i("BGLocationSvc", "On Create");
        buildGoogleApiClient();
    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

        PowerManager mgr = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

    /*
    WakeLock is reference counted so we don't want to create multiple WakeLocks. So do a check before initializing and acquiring.
    This will fix the "java.lang.Exception: WakeLock finalized while still held: MyWakeLock" error that you may find.
    */
        if (this.mWakeLock == null) { //**Added this
            this.mWakeLock = mgr.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "MyWakeLock");
        }

        if (!this.mWakeLock.isHeld()) { //**Added this
           this.mWakeLock.acquire();
        }

        if (!servicesAvailable || mInProgress)
            return START_STICKY;
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() || !mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting() && !mInProgress) {
            appendLog(DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date()) + ": Started", Constants.LOG_FILE);
            mInProgress = true;
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }



    public void appendLog(String text, String filename) {
        File logFile = new File(filename);
        if (!logFile.exists()) {
            try {
                logFile.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        try {
            //BufferedWriter for performance, true to set append to file flag
            BufferedWriter buf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(logFile, true));
            buf.append(text);
            buf.newLine();
            buf.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // Turn off the request flag
        this.mInProgress = false;
        if (this.servicesAvailable && this.mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            this.mGoogleApiClient.unregisterConnectionCallbacks(this);
            this.mGoogleApiClient.unregisterConnectionFailedListener(this);
            this.mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
            // Destroy the current location client
            this.mGoogleApiClient = null;
        }
        // Display the connection status
        // Toast.makeText(this, DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date()) + ":
        // Disconnected. Please re-connect.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (this.mWakeLock != null) {
            this.mWakeLock.release();
            this.mWakeLock = null;
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    /*
     * Called by Location Services when the request to connect the
     * client finishes successfully. At this point, you can
     * request the current location or start periodic updates
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
            mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(10);  // Update location every 30    second. 10 = 1 second

        IntentFilter filter = new     IntentFilter("com.amt.trackertest.BroadcastReceiver");

        LocationReceiver myReceiver = new LocationReceiver();
        registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocationReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent
                .getBroadcast(this, 54321, intent,    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,     Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions
            return;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(this.mGoogleApiClient,
            mLocationRequest, pendingIntent);

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection has been suspend");
    }

    /*
     * Called by Location Services if the attempt to
     * Location Services fails.
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection has failed");
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Building GoogleApiClient");
        this.mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<service android:name=".BackgroundLocationService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true"/>
<receiver android:name="com.amt.trackertest.LocationReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.amt.trackertest.BroadcastReceiver"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And I start the Background service like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), BackgroundLocationService.class);
i.putExtra("foo", "bar");
ComponentName service = v.getContext().startService(i);
```

I enter to the service and build the google api client, but the receiver it's never called.

P.D.: I'm barely new on Android development, I know there is still a long way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED] The problem was that I never connected the GoogleApiClient, I thought it was done on onStartComand inside an if clause, but this clause was always false, then never the Api was connected.